# Custom Drop down Z-Index Issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap drop down on my modal dialog.
After clicking on drop down button drop down menu appears under form.
Is there any way to fix this issue, but without using "position:fixed",because by using fixed attribute I am facing with other issues.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" ng-show='showDialog'>
    <div class="container">
       <h2>Dropdown</h2>
       <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
          <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#">AAAAAA</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">BBBBBB</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CCCCCC</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">DDDDDD</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">EEEEEE</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">FFFFFF</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[See the dropdwon plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2yqfPJGTNVyi18J9Q7Vq?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the dialog, wich is a div, efectively "contains" the dropdown and all it's contents, so the drowpdown stacking context is surrogated to it.

You can add this css rule to overcome your problem, but take it carefully so it doesn't have any side effects in other dialogs on your app:

```
<style>
  .ui-dialog, #dialog, #container { overflow:visible; }
</style>
```

You also have a great article [here](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) explaining stacking contexts as Z-Index isn't what most people think...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.In this case it is work, everything is fine, just I am working on a big project with other developers and I must create custom drop down via angularjs and this dropdown doesn't make any side effects for others forms.I should fix this issue in my directive, without touching any outer styles. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't use Bootstrap nor jQueryMobile just for these kind of things, they create DOM elements and move them arround in a quite funky way....

Comment: If you can take your ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl" attribute to the html tag, then your body tag will be "different" for each view in your app. This gives the chance to mark it with an id or a class, and then you could make the css rule more specific, i.e. for the dialogs inside one specific body tag:  #theBody .ui-dialog { ... }

Comment: But why standard select element doesn't make any stacking context issues on html??I mean that I can put standard select dropdown everywhere I want without facing this kind of stacking issues.There is no way to make this behavior on my custom dropdown? Again thanks for your answer